# C++ External Class Implementation Not Working

Tags: c++, class, oop, g++, implementation

I am trying to implement my own 'User' class from an external C++ file.
Therefore, I created a **User.h**, **User.cpp** and **main.cpp** file which are all in the same directory. Here you can see the source code of each file:

**./User.h**

```
#include <string>

class User {
    public:
        User(std::string username, std::string password);
        std::string getPassword();
        std::string username;

    private:
        std::string password;
};
```

**./User.cpp**

```
#include "User.h"

User::User(std::string username, std::string password) {
    this -> username = username;
    this -> password = password;
}
std::string User::getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

**./main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "User.h"

int main() {
    User eve("Eve3033", "Pass1234");
    std::cout << eve.getPassword();
    return 0;
}
```

**The g++ compiler error:**

```
undefined reference to `User::User(std::\__cxx11::basic_string\<char, std::char_traits\<char\>, std::allocator\<char\> \>, std::\__cxx11::basic_string\<char, std::char_traits\<char\>, std::allocator\<char\> \>)'
C:\\Users\\wise-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ccQgLvm9.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `User::getPassword[abi:cxx11]()' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to remove the `std::string User::getPassword()` method, which didn't result in any compiling errors. The construction of the `User eve("Eve3033", "Pass1234")` instance was also successfull and I was able to access the `public std::string username` attribute.

However, when I tried to implement the `std::string User::getPassword()` method to also access the `private std:string password`  attribute, g++ returned the same error.

I searched for the error online and found the following links:

- [Undefined reference to Class::Method()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737853/undefined-reference-to-classmethod)
- [Undefined Reference to Class::Function() in C++](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/cpp-undefined-reference-to-class-function/)
- [How to fix undefined reference in C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5317982/How-to-I-fix-undefined-reference-in-Cplusplus)

I hope you have any ideas on that problem :)

Comment: Please show the commands you used to compile your project, not just the output.

Comment: My first guess is that User.cpp wasn't included in the g++ command.

Comment: If you are using VSCode remember that by default it builds only the active file. The documentation explains that and tells you how to modify your `tasks.json` when you have more than 1 source file.

Comment: ***Therefore, I created a User.h, User.cpp and main.cpp file which are all in the same directory.*** The location is not the absolute determining factor. What matters is how you are compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error *must* be due to a syntax error or missing file in your command. Compiling this code in VS works just fine, and has the expected output. Make sure you have: `g++ main.cpp user.cpp`

If you need more context and examples, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files).